# Парсинг домена/субдомена из URL

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер, python-3.5

Решаю задачу с сайта codewars. Суть состоит в том, что нужно вытащить название домена из url адреса. Однако в процессе возникли сложности, и вместе с результатом выводится ненужные мне символы.

Мой код:

```
import re
github = 'https://github.com'
pattern = re.search(r'/\w+[a-z]\w+[a-z]', github)
print(pattern.group())
```

В чем моя ошибка, и как его лучше доработать для правильной работы?

Comment: что вы считаете доменом - `github.com` или `github` или `com`?

Comment: Просто github))

Comment: можете привести несколько примеров входных и выходных данных? Например что вы ожидаете получить на выходе для `https://www.subdomain.domain.com` ?

Comment: Только subdomain

Comment: То есть в ''https//www.google.com'' нужно получить google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсинг URL при помощи чистого RegEx - очень неблагодарная задача. Попробуйте, например, написать корректный RegEx, который сумеет обрабатывать как обычные домены, так и [многоуровневые домены](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk#Second-level_domains)). Другие примеры:

- [.br](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.br#Second-level_domains)
- [.tz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.tz)

Судя по уточнениям из комментариев, вы хотите извлекать либо домен либо саб-домен, в зависимости от сложности URL. Стандартные решения (например [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html)) такого не умеют.

Можно воспользоваться модулем [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/) для корректного разбиения URL на `subdomain` и `domain`. Далее для того чтобы игнорировать стандартные префиксы - такие как: `www.` и `web.`, можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями.

```
In [162]: pat
Out[162]: '^(?:www|web)\\.'
```

Код:

```
import re
from tldextract import extract   #  pip install tldextract

def get_domain(url):    
    subdomain, domain, suffix = extract(url)
    ignored = ["www", "web"]
    if not subdomain or subdomain.lower() in ignored:
        return domain
    pat = r"^(?:{})\.".format("|".join(ignored))
    return re.sub(pat, "", subdomain)
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [144]: get_domain("https://github.com")
Out[144]: 'github'

In [145]: get_domain("https://www.github.com")
Out[145]: 'github'

In [146]: get_domain("https://www.google.com")
Out[146]: 'google'

In [147]: get_domain("https://subdomain.domain.com")
Out[147]: 'subdomain'

In [148]: get_domain("https://www.subdomain.domain.com")
Out[148]: 'subdomain'

In [149]: get_domain("https://www.subdomain1.subdomain2.domain.co.uk")
Out[149]: 'subdomain1.subdomain2'
```

Comment: Выглядит весьма устрашающе) Много вопросов вызывает дополнительный модуль, который Вы вызвали. Еще непонятно, что происходит в переменной pat. Буду очень благодарен за объяснение)

Comment: @PythonLearner4823, дополнил ответ...

Comment: Дело в том, что я недавно здесь и мне привычней благодарить текстом) Но раз так, буду придерживаться правил)